# TLS handshake is failing

Tags: ssl, handshake

I'm stuck, hope somebody can help me.

I need to write a python test (under 'pytest') to verify TLS communication between a windows PC and an embedded target board.

As an intermediate step I have downloaded and built openssl from here https://www.openssl.org/source/ and run it from a cmd window like this:

```
As a server:    openssl s_server -accept 49152 -nocert -psk 1a2b3c4d
Or as a client: openssl s_client -port 49152 -psk 1a2b3c4d -tls1_3
```

The embedded target acts as a TLS1.3 client and connects fine with the above openssl server (when I use a matching psk).

But I need to run the TLS server with pyopenssl. I have both a server and a client based on pyopenssl, and when I run them together they work fine.
However, when I run the python versions against either the target board - or the windows openssl, then it always fails like this:
The client sends 'Client Hello' as expected, but the server responds with...

```
  Alert Message
      Level: Fatal (2)
      Description: Illegal Parameter (47)
```

(It doesn't tell which parameter is illegal)

The following combinations are failing the same way:

1. the windows openssl as server <--> the python version as client
2. the windows openssl as client <--> the python version as server

So: What am I doing wrong with my python script?
I am using python version 3.10.2. Here is the server code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from openssl_psk import patch_context

patch_context()

server_addr = '127.0.0.1'
server_port = 49152

psk_value : str = '1a2b3c4d'
PSK_MAP = {b'Client_identity': psk_value}

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def server_callback(conn_2, client_identity):
        return PSK_MAP[client_identity]

    ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLS_METHOD)
    ctx.set_options(SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1)
    ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_NONE)
    ctx.use_psk_identity_hint('Client_identity')     # seems not to be necessary in server
    ctx.set_psk_server_callback(server_callback)

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    conn_1 = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
    conn_1.bind((server_addr, server_port))
    ctx.set_cipher_list(b"AES128-GCM-SHA256")
    conn_1.listen(1)

    while True:
        print('\tWaiting for client to connect...\r\n')
        newsocket, fromaddr = conn_1.accept()
        print ('Server accepted a socket-request')
        conn_2 = SSL.Connection(ctx, newsocket)
        conn_2.set_accept_state()
        conn_2.do_handshake()

        # bla bla
```

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl s_client -port 49152 -psk 1a2b3c4d -tls1_3
...
psk_value : str = '1a2b3c4d'
PSK_MAP = {b'Client_identity': psk_value}
```

`s_client` and `s_server` expect the psk as hexadecimal encoded. The python code must supply the original not encoded version tough to the callback, i.e.

```
PSK_MAP = {b'Client_identity': bytes.fromhex(psk_value) }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, now it works. Thanks a LOT!!!